# Comparing unicode and wchar_t C++ : `unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""F'`

Tags: c++, unicode, wchar-t

So I have a `wchar_t tempc;`.  I want to see if it's in the unicode range 000000-00007F.

This is how I tried to compare the values:

```
if ((tempc < (wchar_t)000000) || (tempc > (wchar_t)00007F)) { ...
```

I thought this would convert the unicode values 000000 and 00007F to wchar_t. But I get errors such as:

```
error: invalid suffix "F" on integer constant
error: invalid digit "8" in octal constant
error: invalid suffix "FF" on integer constant
error: invalid digit "8" in octal constant
```

So clearly the compiler doesn't how that values like 00007F are unicode. What is my misunderstanding here? Do I convert them to unicode first (if so, how?), THEN to wchar_t?

Comment: You should use `0x` prefix for hex numbers

Comment: Hexadecimal values start with `0x`. Values starting with just a `0` are octal.

Comment: It worked, thank you. But I am confused.. Is 'unicode' and 'hexadecimal'  synonymous?

Comment: Unicode codepoint values are (usually) written using the [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) number system. http://unicode.org/charts/

Comment: You don't have to write the numbers in hex; `0x7F` can also be written `127`, or `0177`. So the code could be `(tempc < (wchar_t)0 || tempc > (wchar_t)127)` or `(tempc < (wchar_t)0 || tempc > (wchar_t)0177)`. But since everyone else just uses hex it's easiest to just copy the hex value instead of doing the math to convert to decimal or octal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ a constant value starting with 0 is an octal number. As such, it cannot contain 8 nor F. The hexadecimal constant should write `0x7F`. Just write:

```
if ((tempc < (wchar_t)0) || (tempc > (wchar_t)0x7F)) { ...
```